# TFS - Get Latest checks out every file in the solution even if there were no changes

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, tfs

I've been having this problem for awhile now. Every time I 'Get Latest (Recursive)' the solution, it checks out every file in that solution. Not just the ones with changes. Normally, it wouldn't be a problem. But these solution has thousands of files and it's very cumbersome to check out everything every time there is a new build. 'Get Specific' does the same too.

I hope somebody can provide a solution, I've tried searching the web for this but to no luck.

Thanks.

Edit for clarity.

Comment: Does it check out every single file or just the solution and project files? Is anyone else in your company experiencing this behaviour?

Comment: When you say "check out" do you mean it pends a change on each file and each file shows up in the pending changes list or that all of the files are downloaded? Is it just the files that have changed on the server that are downloaded or is it all of your files?

Comment: What are you using to Check-Out - command line or IDE. What version IDE VS2005, VS2008, VS2010, VS2012 ? Can you include a summary of the output windows or cmd output. Thanks